# In a Ruby / an IRB, how can I use the yard documentation gem to interact with the code's stats and parsed information?

Tags: ruby, parsing, irb, yard

The yard gem is a tool for generating docs of ruby code.

It's done via the command line, and the docs get generated.

However I was wondering if it's possible to interact with the parsed code and statistic via an IRB.

You can go into the IRB and call up yard like this:

```
require 'yard'
YARD
```

However I can't seem to interact with the code or get and parsed stats. For example getting the list of methods in the code would be great, or a object of method lists via the parser.

Docs: (http://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/YARD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See documentation on the [YARD::Registry](http://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/YARD/Registry) (linked to from the [Architecture Overview document](http://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Overview.md)) for accessing code objects that got parsed out after you ran `yard`.

Example for printing all methods in your registry:

```
require 'yard'

YARD::Registry.load!
puts YARD::Registry.all(:method).map(&:path)
```

Advanced class-- getting all undocumented objects:

```
require 'yard'

YARD::Registry.load!
puts YARD::Registry.all.select {|o| o.docstring.blank? }.map(&:path)
```

You can see more properties of CodeObjects in the [CodeObjects Architecture Overview](http://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/CodeObjects.md) in addition to the [YARD::CodeObjects::Base](http://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/YARD/CodeObjects/Base) class API docs. That will give you more information on what you can query. You may also want to look at the [YARD::Docstring](http://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/YARD/Docstring) class if you plan on introspecting tags.

Note that if you want to actually generate the registry (you haven't yet run `yard`), you can do so with the Registry class, but it would probably be better to use [YARD::CLI::Yardoc.run](http://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/YARD/CLI/Yardoc#run-instance_method) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to the yard source it seems like the gem is not meant to be use with that purpose but you can extract some info.

```
require 'yard'

stats = YARD::CLI::Stats.new
stats.run(files) # it allows patter matching, for instance 'lib/*.rb'
stats.all_objects # all the objects recognized by the parser

stats.all_objects.select{|o| o.type == :method} # to get only methods
stats.all_objects.select{|o| o.type == :class} # to get only classes
```

I'm not sure if that is enough for you but I don't think you can get information in a deeper level.

Comment: This always results in 0 stats or an empty array, no matter what file paths params I pass into .run(files)

Comment: YARD is absolutely meant to be used programmatically. There is a whole API and guide about that use case: http://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/YARD/Registry

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you need to do, but I strongly suggest you to take a look at [pry](http://pryrepl.org/) that lets you do great things:

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'cgi'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> show-method CGI::escape

From: /home/carlesso/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/cgi/util.rb @ line 7:
Owner: CGI::Util
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 6

def escape(string)
  encoding = string.encoding
  string.b.gsub(/([^ a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/) do |m|
    '%' + m.unpack('H2' * m.bytesize).join('%').upcase
  end.tr(' ', '+').force_encoding(encoding)
end
```

and even more strange stuff:

```
[4] pry(main)> cd CGI
[5] pry(CGI):1> ls
constants: 
  Cookie  CR  EOL  HtmlExtension  HTTP_STATUS  InvalidEncoding  LF  MAX_MULTIPART_COUNT  MAX_MULTIPART_LENGTH  NEEDS_BINMODE  PATH_SEPARATOR  QueryExtension  REVISION  Util
Object.methods: yaml_tag
CGI::Util#methods: 
  escape  escapeElement  escapeHTML  escape_element  escape_html  h  pretty  rfc1123_date  unescape  unescapeElement  unescapeHTML  unescape_element  unescape_html
CGI.methods: accept_charset  accept_charset=  parse
CGI#methods: accept_charset  header  http_header  nph?  out  print
class variables: @@accept_charset
locals: _  __  _dir_  _ex_  _file_  _in_  _out_  _pry_
```

you can also edit something, like `edit CGI::escape` will open your `$EDITOR` to the relevant file/line (in my case, vim will be opened at `.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/cgi/util.rb` line 7

Where present will show the help:

```
[10] pry(CGI):1> help Pry.hist
Usage:   hist [--head|--tail]
         hist --all
         hist --head N
         hist --tail N
         hist --show START..END
         hist --grep PATTERN
         hist --clear
         hist --replay START..END
         hist --save [START..END] FILE
Aliases: history

Show and replay Readline history.

    -a, --all              Display all history
    -H, --head             Display the first N items
    -T, --tail             Display the last N items
    -s, --show             Show the given range of lines
    -G, --grep             Show lines matching the given pattern
    -c, --clear            Clear the current session's history
    -r, --replay           Replay a line or range of lines
        --save             Save history to a file
    -e, --exclude-pry      Exclude Pry commands from the history
    -n, --no-numbers       Omit line numbers
    -h, --help             Show this message.
```

But, again, it really depends on your needs, a little bit of "metaprogramming" can help you, like `.methods`, `.instance_variables`, `.constants` can be useful..

Comment: Yeah I thought about pry, but yard gets all the classes and categorizes them, it looks at the code comments and gets descriptions / params ect. It's specifically the yard stats and info I want to manipulate.